# parse - edit array in parse user class

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a little problem with loading and sending data to parse.com.

I want to read an Array from parse User Class, adding it and send it back to parse.com.

The following code shows how it would work for a "normal" Class to send an array:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myOwnClass"];
   [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"myObjectID"
                         block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

                             [gameScore addUniqueObjectsFromArray:@[@"Name1", @"Name1"] forKey:@"Friends"];
                             [gameScore saveInBackground]; }];
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more what exactly you want to do?

Comment: also what is happening? Does your old array get replaced by the new one?

Comment: what is normal class ? myOwnClass is logic data class, you will define in Parse.com. is It normal class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Get The Array...Change your PFQuery Method:**

```
 -(void)FetchFromPFUserClass{
        PFQuery*query = [PFUser query];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"myObjectID"
                                 block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

           if(error==nil){

      [gameScore addUniqueObjectsFromArray:@[@"Name1", @"Name1"] forKey:@"Friends"];
         [gameScore saveInBackground];


        }

     }];

 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
But how can I load an Array from Parse User Class?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you again